# Does my DBMS persist after reboot?

Tags: oracle-apex

I downloaded Oracle Database 11g Express Edition, and set the httpport to 9090 by using the command

```
exec dbms_xdb.sethttpport(9090);
```

Now I can access APEX any time I go to http://localhost:9090/apex on any browser. Even after restarting my computer. How is this possible? Does oracle start on my computer every time I boot it up, or is it somehow wrapped in the browser code?

Also is there documentation explaining this somewhere?

Comment: What OS are you running? How did you install it?

Comment: Windows. I just downloaded it from the website, I'm using it with Wildfly in Eclipse

Comment: The installer likely sets itself up as a Windows Service and also sets up a webserver for APEX too. Check the Services MMC snap-in.

Comment: How wouldn't it make sense that a DB wouldn't set itself up to be up all the time... And since the DB will be running with EPG (embedded plsql gateway), the apex environment will be approachable when the DB is up. You'd be SO MUCH better off with using virtualbox and running a DB in a VM. There are even pre-built machines. Unless you want to go through the ordeal of installing the DB on your machine itself, a VM is a much better option.

Comment: I'm just following instructions. More importantly I'm new to this and this is the only way I can get my DB to work and access it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The oracle DB persists after installation in the form of a autostarting service called OracleServiceXE, which can call upon APEX.